# Variable number of arguments and recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion, optional-arguments

I wanted to write a recursive function that takes a *variable number of arguments* (each argument being an iterable list or set) and returns a set of all concatenated combinations of each argument. I learned how to [write functions with a variable number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/python-can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function) and I know how to write recursive functions, but I don't know how to put those two together in Python (or if it is even possible).

Here's my code:

```
def generate_combinations( *args ):
    # returns all combinations of each of the arguments
    if len( args ) == 1:
        return set( args[0] )

    result = set()
    lastdigits = generate_combinations( args[1:] )
    for d in args[0]:
         result.add( d + lastdigits )      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lastDigit = [ '1', '2', '3' ]
    allDigits = [ '4', '5' ]
    print("{}".format( generate_combinations( allDigits, lastDigit )))
```

Expected output:

```
14
15
24
25
34
35
```

The *"problem"* with my code lies in line 7: `lastdigits = generate_combinations( args[1:] )`. What I wanted to do here, is to pass all original arguments *except the first one* to the function (thus creating the recursion). And this is obviously not the way to do that. My question: can this be done, and how?

Ps: I know I can accomplish the same using a list of lists with one argument, but I'm curious is this is at all possible.

Comment: `lastdigits = generate_combinations( *args[1:] )`

Comment: [Pass elements of a list as arguments to a function in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756116/pass-elements-of-a-list-as-arguments-to-a-function-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requested job is done by these lines :

```
args = list(args)
args.pop(0)
recursiveCall( *tuple(args) )
```

Here the implementation of your function was a little buggy ( or I misunderstand your use of set maybe ).

```
def generate_combinations( *args, **kwargs ):
    print("called with", args)
    #terminate recursion
    if len(args) == 1:
        return list(set(args[0]))

    #recursion
    else:
        result = []
        args = list(args)
        heads = args.pop(0)
        tails = generate_combinations( *args, **kwargs )
        for head in heads:
            for tail in tails:
                result.append(head + tail)
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    allDigits = [ '1', '2', '3' ]
    lastDigit = [ '4', '5' ]
    letters   = [ 'a', 'b' ]
    print("{}".format( generate_combinations( allDigits, lastDigit, letters , Useless='parameter')))
```

Execution give :

```
['14a', '14b', '15a', '15b', '24a', '24b', '25a', '25b', '34a', '34b', '35a', '35b']
```

Hope you enjoy this ;)

Arthur.

Comment: Learned a lot! Thank you very much! Could you just explain why the `tuple` is needed? I understand the `*`, but why add the `tuple` in the line where the function is called recursively?

Comment: There's no need for that - you can unpack lists with `*` too

Comment: For future reference, I think it's because the complete definition of a variable argument function is `def f( *args, **kwargs )`. I assume the tuple refers to the args and kwargs tuple (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: no jonrsharpe is good, there is no need for the tuple. I edited my code for completeness reasons. Added **kwargs that aren't use to show you how to handle **keywordargs too.